# AutoHotkey Terraria

Tags: autohotkey

I'm extremely new to using AutoHotkey and I can not figure out how to send multiple lines of commands on a Terraria server. What I'm trying to do is make a buff quick set, for example I would press CTRL+S and the hotkey would send {Enter}/buff name 545{Enter} and go on to the next buff. I got the lines to send in a text file or Steam chat, but it will not work in Terraria.

Comment: Try this with any other game. I believe the steam overlay makes it difficult to do this. Also, try it with a sendkeys program. If you need one let me know and I can link you to one I made (however not for this purpose)

Comment: If you could send me it that would be much appreciated. I'll hopefully be able to examine and morph it to my needs.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mos325brz8r6uzu) you go. [Virus scan](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/dd56cb48dbbd707923ad08cb754b5ef77a64c89846b7161b3cf75691d00f2b57/analysis/1381183914/). You'll probably want to click "Only send once". To send the enter key use {ENTER}.

Answer (score 1):

Terraria polls keys unless you're typing in the chat box.
you have to hold the Enter key for 1/fps to open the chat box, type, then hold Enter again for 1/fps to send the message.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SendChat(msg)
{
    Send {Enter down}
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter up}%msg%
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter down}
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter up}
    Sleep 100
}

MButton::
SendChat("/help 1")
SendChat("/help 2")
SendChat("/help 3")
SendChat("/help 4")
```